# WPF NotifyIcon - ContextMenu Position

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu, notifyicon

Im using the WPF NotifyIcon from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon). It works fine but what I noticed is that when compiling with .NET 4.0 the ContextMenu is always positioned above the taskbar, it's fine with .NET 3.5:

.NET 3.5

[image: .NET 3.5]

.NET 4.0

[image: .NET 4.0]

I played around with the position values inside the TaskbarIcon Class but the ContextMenu just doesn't want to get in front of the taskbar:

```
    ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.AbsolutePoint;
    ContextMenu.HorizontalOffset = cursorPosition.X;
    ContextMenu.VerticalOffset = cursorPosition.Y;
```

I already asked about this in the [comment section on CodePlex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon?msg=4249280#xx4249280xx) Page a few weeks ago but didn't receive an answer.

Does anyone have a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: That's Code*Project*, not Code*Plex*. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I use is this class to determine the location of the task bar, and then place the context menu based on that instead of the cursor position.

[How can I determine programmatically whether the Windows taskbar is hidden or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032461/how-can-i-determine-programmatically-whether-the-windows-taskbar-is-hidden-or-no#answer-2032557)